# Прочитать данные из файла

Tags: python

Есть задание в котором нужно прочитать данные из файла, добавить их в список и отсортировать по длине строки. Проблема состоит в том, что когда я читаю файл созданный в блокноте, а не в PyCharm, то выбивает ошибку юникода, хотя я поставил UTF-8, а когда читаю файл созданный в PyCharm, то в выводе появляются "\n", которые мне там ни к чему. Помогите понять в чём проблема.
Вот код:

```
file = open(r'H:\Python\Python files\lab6(ipz_19_1_saukh)\files\learning_python.txt', 'r+', encoding="UTF-8")
lst = list(file.readlines())
lst_new = sorted(lst, key=len)
print(lst)
print(lst_new)
file.close()
```

Comment: какая именно ошибка?

Comment: @Danis Оно начинает ругаться на lst = list(file.readlines()), и выдаёт ошибку UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 0: invalid continuation byte

Comment: На английском вывод таков
['hello\n', 'my\n', 'dear\n', 'friend']
['my\n', 'dear\n', 'hello\n', 'friend']

Comment: string.decode('utf-8')  # or:
unicode(string, 'utf-8')

Comment: А если в файле кирилица, то выдаёт ошибку

Comment: @Jack_oS Так у меня же список из строк, как туда внедрить вашу конструкцию?

Answer (score 0):

Избавиться от переводов строки:

```
a = ['hello\n', 'my\n', 'dear\n', 'friend']
a = list(map(str.strip, a))
print(a)
```

Вывод:

```
['hello', 'my', 'dear', 'friend']
```

Избавиться от проблем с кодировкой при чтении файла записанного в блокноте скорее всего можно выбрав кодировку windows при чтении файла:

```
file = open(..., encoding="cp1251")
```